# Select ids associated with combination of values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where I store product parameters like:

```
productId | parameterValue
--------------------------
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
2         | 1
3         | 3
```

What I need is to select distinct productIds that are associated with parameterValues `1 AND 2 AND 3`. So I cannot simply use `WHERE parameterValue IN (1,2,3)` as it would return productIds associated to any of these values.

What is the most efficient approach to query this? The table has hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: GROUP BY id, COUNT the number of records within the grouping, and use HAVING to filter out only those records where the count matches the number of parameters you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by filtering the rows for the parameter values you want, then counting how many there are for each product and using the `HAVING` clause to only get those that have three (in your case) of them:

```
select  productId
from    yourTable
where   parameterValue in (1, 2, 3)
group by productId
having   count(distinct parameterValue) = 3
```

Comment: @Tomage Note that if each combination is unique (as it should be), then DISTINCT is redundant in this context.

Comment: Regarding the redundand DISTINCT ... should there be any noticeable performance difference if used or not? Since it returns distinct values anyway, the overhead should be really small, right?